# Set objects by using a p:commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

So I have a bean like this. It holds the `currentPara` which will be used later in another bean (which should only hold one type of `Para`). 
This `currentPara` is either a `ParaA` or a `ParaB`.

```
public class ParaBuilderBean {
    private Para currentPara;
    private ParaA paraA;
    private ParaB paraB;
}

public class ParaA extends Para{
    private List<String> strings;
    private String currentString;
}

public class ParaB extends Para{
    private int min;
    private int max;
}
```

For each `ParaX` there is a `p:commandButton`. By clicking on one, the matched .xhtml gets set in `paraPanelBean`. This is my `main.xhtml`.

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <p:commandButton value="ParaA" update="@form" actionListener="#{paraPanelBean.setCurrentPanel('paraAPanel')}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="ParaB" update="@form" actionListener="#{paraPanelBean.setCurrentPanel('paraBPanel')}"/>
    <ui:include src="#{paraPanelBean.currentPanel}.xhtml" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

So for each type of `Para` there should be a different .xhtml. Each .xhtml holds individual elements to set the fields of its `Para` type. For example `paraAPanel.xhtml`:

```
<h:panelGrid>
    <p:outputLabel value="Enter String" />
    <p:inputText value="#{paraBuilderBean.paraA.currentString}"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Add" ajax="false">
            <p:collector value="#{paraBuilderBean.paraA.currentString}" unique="false" addTo="#{paraBuilderBean.paraA.strings}"></p:collector>
        </p:commandButton>
</h:panelGrid>
```

So now my question:

How to set the `currentPara` of my `ParaBuilderBean` to the choosen one by using a `p:commandButton` in `main.xhtml`? I want to achieve something like `action="#{paraBuilderBean.setCurrentPara(paraBuilderBean.paraA)}"`.

Comment: 1 Question per question please... Otherwise answering and commenting becomes unreadble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this could do the job

```
<p:commandButton value="ParaA" update="@form" actionListener="#{paraPanelBean.setCurrentPanel('paraAPanel')}">
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{paraBuilderBean.currentPara}" value="#{paraBuilderBean.paraA}" />
</p:commandButton>
```